Failed to convert the pandas datetime object to another format
I tried to convert a python datetime object to another format as below
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime(['1/1/1900']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m')

However above code generates error.
Could you please tell me what would be the right approach

Did you try just pd.to_datetime(['1/1/1900']).strftime('%Y-%m')?

At least share what error it throws.

pd.to_datetime creates a DatetimeIndex object, which does not have a dt function.
Try:
pd.to_datetime(['1/1/1900']).strftime('%Y-%m')

Output:
Index(['1900-01'], dtype='object')

Using dt would make sense if you assign it as a column in a DataFrame, changing the type to a pd.Series.
The you could do:
df['col'] = pd.to_datetime(['1/1/1900', '2/1/1900','3/1/1900'])
df['col'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')

Output:
0    1900-01
1    1900-02
2    1900-03
Name: col, dtype: object

